# Retina Display on iPad3 displaying fuzzy text

Tags: ipad, text, retina-display, core-text, ipad-3

Currently when displaying some fonts on iPad 3 using core text, the ipad 3 displays them a little bit fuzzy and not as sharp. When these same texts are displayed using a webview on the ipad 3 the the text is very sharp, as expected....does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

Is there an issue with coretext displaying fonts on a retina display? It is definately not the fonts as we  are using the same font type, colour etc...

Answer (score 9):

You can keep layer.rasterize if you add

```
view.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Comment: If you need the rasterization, this is the correct solution. Usually you have a good reason to rasterize and it's a bad thing to turn it off completely.

Comment: When I try to do a view.layer.rasterizationScale I do not get the rasterizationScale option....what sort of Layer are you using?

Comment: did you import quartz? #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: No I didn't have done that now and can access that method but it seems to make no difference to the fuzzy text issue

Answer (score 3):

We figured out our problem with fuzzy text.  As it turns out, it wasn't a text issue at all, but that beautiful, crisp retina text is the first thing you notice on a page.

After closer inspection, we found our whole views were actually blurred, Apple toggle-switches and all.  Each of the offending views had added the line:

```
view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

This was forcing the entire view to rasterize... AT 1x!  For some reason the OS couldn't upscale the rasterized view, so everything was yucky @1x resolution.

I simply removed the line, as the default setting for shouldRasterize is NO.

Comment: When I try to do a view.layer.rasterizationScale I do not get the rasterizationScale option....what sort of Layer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

setting the contentScaleFactor , as described here: [UIView not scaling to iPad retina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771000/uiview-not-scaling-to-ipad-retina)  , worked for me.