# UIView not scaling to iPad retina

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display

I'm updating my app to work with the iPad retina display, but for some reason one of my views doesn't want to scale to 2x. As you can see in the screenshot, the text on the button on the left scales properly, while the text on the right still display the fonts in low resolution. (The gray bg is still low res, but I'm working on that).

I'm adding the ViewControllers as children of the main controller correctly, and the views also follow the same hierarchy.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You should really show us some code.

Comment: there's not really much to change.. I'm just doing the simple addSubview/addChildControllers when necessary.. That works correctly on the iPhone retina, but doesn't seem to work on the iPad..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. For some reason the contentScaleFactor is not being set properly in the subview. Setting it manually did the trick:

```
self.reportsController.view.contentScaleFactor = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Comment: setting the contentScaleFactor worked for me on the new ipad, for some reason the entire app looked fuzzy before setting the contentScaleFactor.